# LVCOLUMN ListView ColumnHeader Image padding and alignment c# .net 3.5 winform

Tags: c#, winapi, listview, imagelist, columnheader

Using the procedure in the following article [Microsoft Support Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314933) It is possible to add an image from an ImageList into the ColumnHeader of a ListView control.

However the Image is always on the left of the text, and the image/text has a large amount of padding.

Ideally I would like to be able to control the padding - remove it so the text sits next to the image, or align the image to the right of the text.

Looking where my nose takes me [LVCOLUMN MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I cannot find a way of gaining this level of control over the image.

Is there a reasonable way of doing this?  Will I have to custom draw the header?

I appreciate any response.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to custom draw.  Kinda painful for a ListView but well supported in Winforms without pinvoke.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Hans.  Not what I wanted to hear, but at least I know now!

Comment: @HansPassant I know the answer was short,  but your's is the correct answer and how I worked the solution.  If you add your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Why don't you just post the code that you used.  That would be a more useful answer.

Comment: Sure.  good idea.  will update tomorrow.